value Not Found in Parameterized Test (JUnit5)
I am trying to migrate an application to JUnit5 from JUnit4, the class currently looks like this:
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.contains;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import org.aai.app.util.JettyUtil;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class JettyUtilTest {

    final String[] args;
    final String expected;

    public JettyUtilTest (String description, String[] args, String expected) {

        this.args = args;
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Parameters(value = "{0}")
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {

        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
.
.
.
}

But during compilation I get the below exception:
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method value()
  location: @interface org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters

I was trying to search for examples for this, but couldn't find anything of note. Any pointers would be helpful.

I don't understand your question. You say you're migrating from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5, but the errors you're getting are from a JUnit 4 class. Have you actually got your JUnit 4 tests working before you try to convert them to JUnit 5?

Did you mean to use the name element of the Parameters annotation?

@SotiriosDelimanolis The value field inside the @Parameters is causing the problem.

That specific annotation does not have a value element. It has a name element.
